# How to upload videos from my gallery when building app on android studio

Tags: java, android

Please everyone, i am trying to build an app from the android studio. I want to be able to upload video from my gallery on the app. Please how do i go about it? note: I'm just a beginner

Comment: You must google first....check this.... http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-pick-image-from-gallery/              https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-upload-image-from-gallery-with-text/                                             https://www.androidpit.com/forum/626144/android-image-uploading-to-server-from-gallery

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please read the guides on https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to get a better idea how does SO work.

Comment: Yeah. but its about how to add images not video. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/android-uploading-camera-image-video-to-server-with-progress-bar/ you may get an idea how to upload video with loader showing percentage.

Comment: please can i get a video tutorial ?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9tX85f8vZ5I this may help you it is using retrofit.